# Jquery and Regular Javascript Interference

Tags: javascript, jquery, merge

Im building a site in joomla and I recently purchased a content slider for it that is built in plain old Javascript, then I built some content boxes that have an animation on them provided by Jquery. Right now the animations work, but the slider doesn't. I was wondering how I could get the page to work using both. Here's my code

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script>jQuery.noConflict();
$(document).ready(function() { 
  //settings 
  var opacity = 0.5, toOpacity = 1, duration = 350; 
  //set opacity ASAP and events 
  $('.opacity').css('opacity',opacity).hover(function() { 
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,toOpacity); 
    }, function() { 
      $(this).fadeTo(duration,opacity); 
    } 
  ); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery *is* Javascript, they will (should) both work together without issue. Without examples of the code you're working with though, we'll be of no help here.

Comment: if you remove the jquery code does the slider work then?
if so you probably have some function name's alt. global variable name interfering with eachother

Comment: yes, when I remove the jquery the slider does work. I'm about to paste the code so you all can see it

Comment: when you call `noConflict` you can't use the `$` function unless you alias it `(function($){...})(jQuery);` the simple fix is to change all `$`'s to `jQuery`

Answer (score 2):

Try calling this after the libraries are loaded:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
```

Also, try replacing your jQuery ready function with this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

This passes the $ shortcut into the jQuery code block, but should still avoid conflicts outside it.

You can read up on the subject [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries) in the jQuery docs.

Comment: I inserted this code and it works, but now my Jquery doesnt want to play its animation

Comment: I updated to try and fix you.  If that doesn't work, try replacing your jQuery `$` shortcut where you do your animations with `jQuery` instead.  For instance, `jQuery.animate(//animate stuff);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for potential conficts that may have occurred ($'s in the code)? You can  run your jquery script in no conflict mode to fix that

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Comment: I tried that, but now the jquery animation isnt working. Is it because I might have the code positioned too far down in my head tag?

Answer (score 0):

According to the jQuery [docs on jQuery.noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)...

> Description: Relinquish jQuery's control of the $ variable.

So that means that after you call it, you must use `jQuery` instead of `$` for jQuery calls.

For example, change `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` to `jQuery(document).ready(function() { ... });`.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, so do I do that for all of the $ in the code?

Comment: Awesome! I went ahead and changed them all and it worked. Thanks renesis and everyone who helped

Comment: @Carlos - you can vote on or accept answers if they helped you!